# MongoDB migration from local host to a Linux server

Tags: django, linux, mongodb, server, redhat

So, I have a Django app, that is connected to a MongoDB database on my local machine.
I brought my Django app on a Redhat Linux server. So, now I need MongoDB to be installed on the server:
1- Do I need to have access to the root on Linux server to install MongoDB?
2- I could not find any straight forward instruction to what to do for migration of MongoDB. Do know any references?
I appreciate if you could help me with this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should capture the database file:
Find this directory on windows cmd:
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Tools\100\bin
write the following in the cmd:
“mongoexport --db  --collection  --out
output.json”
find the database JSON file in that directory

Now you should export you database to the server directory:
scp -r /mnt/d/database.json
@:/home/...

Now you should import the mongodb database:
mongoimport --db  --collection  --file